# Find elements with class which end for "...-find"

Tags: jquery, html

I have such html template

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <select name="options[]" class="form-control trololo trololo-lo" multiple>
      <option class="active">1</option>
      <option class="active">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
   </select>
<input type="text" class="form-control trololo trololo-lo" />
<input type="text" class="form-control trololo" />
<select name="options[]" class="form-control trololo trololo-lo" multiple>
   <option class="active">1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
```

I need use jquery which clean up the elements that have a class trololo-lo and put selected the elements that have a class active

Comment: `clean up` meaning remove?

Comment: @AmmarCSE nope, it's meen empty field

Comment: jquery offers selectors for substring matching. Take a look at the documentation. That way you get the list of matching elements which you then can iterate through and check the class per element and handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your select elements you just need to traverse your select elements' options and check to see whether they have that specific class.

As far as removing elements with class `trololo-lo` a simple call to `remove()` will do the job. In this case you had that class on both selects so it would remove both. To show you the select active portion I just took out the class from the top select.

```
$("select option").each(function() {
  if (this.className == "active") {
    $(this).attr("selected", true);   
  }
});
$('.trololo-lo').remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szy54ymg/1/

If you want to just reset those elements with that specified class then you can do something like

```
$("select option").each(function() {
  if (this.className == "active") {
   $(this).attr("selected", true);   
  }
});
$('.trololo-lo').val("");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szy54ymg/2/

Of course you will most likely tie this up with some type of event handler (e.g. "click")